# Google Cloud Identity API group memberships Error 403

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-identity

I want to retrieve the users that belong to a specific group.

The request I'm trying to make is described here:
https://cloud.google.com/identity/docs/reference/rest/v1/groups.memberships/list

For the **parent** parameter I use **groups/{my_group_id}**.

**groups/{my_group_id}** is found by using Method: groups.list

However, when I execute the request via the graph explorer it returns a 403 Error.

Comment: Can you update your answer to indicate what you're trying to do and what kind of request you're making? Also, where are you getting this endpoint from? I can't find this format in the [reference docs](https://cloud.google.com/identity/docs/reference/rest/v1/groups.memberships)

Comment: AFAIK, and @JenPerson could confirm this, groups management rely on Google Workspace API (ex GSuite). Therefore the service account (or the user account) need to have a Domain Wide delegation and to be granted in the `admin.google.com` console to access to the Groups API. Can you confirm that you have these authtorizations?

Comment: I believe I do have all the authorizations, otherwise I wouldn't be able to retrieve the list of groups.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that I was missing a G Suite subscription. Activating it resolved the problem.
However, I'm still left wondering as to why I could use one part of the API without a subscription.